# Java Generics - What do the names ID and S mean?

Tags: java, generics

I found below declaration in one of the interfaces in our java application. Can somebody explain what the `ID` and `S` mean? I understand the `T` stands for generic type.

```
public interface CrudRepository<T, ID> extends Repository<T, ID> {
    <S extends T> S save(S var1);
```

Comment: They all are generics, you can name them the way you want (although uppercased single-letters are usually used, purely by convention). `T` and `ID` are class-level generics, `S` is a method-level one.

Comment: @sp00m - can you also please explain this statement - <S extends T> S

Comment: S extends T means, that S, the return type of an operation ( here save ) , must be a subtype of T.

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<S extends T>`, means that `S`, the return type of an operation ( in this case `save` ) , must be a subtype of `T` or equal to `T`

Also as sp00m mentioned in comment these are generics you can name the way you want ,`T` and `ID` are class-level generics, `S` is a method-level one

For more info find here :  [Java-Generics](https://www.baeldung.com/java-generics)

Comment: Actually, the return type must be assignable to T. It can be T itself or a sub-type of T.

Answer (score 1):

All 3 are type parameters.

Unfortunately, the Javadoc of [CrudRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html) does not mention them, but at least [Repository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/Repository.html) does specify 2 of them.

> ```
> T - the domain type the repository manages
> ID - the type of the id of the entity the repository manages
> ```

S must be equal to T or a subclass of T.